# QFileDialog to open multiple files

Tags: python, qt4, qfiledialog

I am trying to show a dialog box to open multiple files but seems like it is not working. The following is a function defined in my Class:

```
def loadFiles(self):
    filter = "TXT (*.txt);;PDF (*.pdf)"
    file_name = QtGui.QFileDialog()
    file_name.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)
    names = file_name.getOpenFileNameAndFilter(self, "Open files", "C\\Desktop", filter)
    print names
```

I thought that the keyword was `QFileDialog.ExistingFiles`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use `getOpenFileNamesAndFilter` instead of `getOpenFileNameAndFilter` (you're missing the `s`).

Comment: yes!!.....only for one stupid `s` the whole thing was not working....... :( Thanks friend!!